# How is gate-screened Coulomb potential derived?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, potential, fourier-transform, coulombs-law

In two-dimensional materials, the Fourier Transform of Coulomb potential $V(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{r}$ is
$$V(\vec{q})=\int V(\vec{r})exp(-i\vec{q}\cdot \vec{r})d^2r=\frac{2\pi}{q}\sim\frac{1}{q}$$
This Fourier Transform suffers from the divergence at $q=0$. Consequently, we frequently employ an alternate form of Coulomb Potential, usually called gate-screened Coulomb potential, whose Fourier Transform is finite at $q=0$
$$V'(\vec{q})\sim\frac{tanh(Dq)}{q}$$
$D$ is the gate-to-sample distance.
My question is how is $V'(\vec{q})$ **derived**? (like how does the gate-screening work?) What is its real space profile (tried Mathematica, but didn't produce anything)?

Comment: No, no, those stuff are not derived. We simply pick functions that are nice and forcibly split the full Coulomb potential into two or more parts that are nice to deal with.

Comment: The 2D sample is kept between two metallic gates, which gives rise to an infinite array of alternating image charges. When one solves the image problem, the effective Coulomb interaction in momentum space is obtained as what you have mentioned in your post. Please note that this form arises when you have two gates. For a single gate one gets $V(q) \sim e^{-q d} / q $.

Comment: @Galilean Thanks for the answer. But why for a single gate, V(q) is $e^{-qd}/q$? I assume that d is the distance between the charge and a single metallic plate, but I got nothing similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck on the same problem for about three months, and was just able to derive the results. The key is to read Jackson's E&M chapter 3.9 to 3.11 where he talked about how to deal with boundary condition problems with a charge distribution.

You always start with the Poisson's equation
$$-\nabla^2\phi(\vec{r}) = \frac{4\pi}{\kappa}\rho(\vec{r}),$$
where $\phi(\vec{r})$ is the Coulomb potential in the real space, $\kappa$ is the relative dielectric constant, $\rho(\vec{r})$ is the charge distribution. To ease the calculation, might as well set $\rho(\vec{r})=\frac{q}{r}\delta(r)\delta(z)$, which means a charge standing at $(x,y,z)=0$. Here, the scalar $r\equiv \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and the $1/r$ factor before the Dirac deltas is from $\delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z)=\frac{1}{\text{Jacobian}(r,\varphi,z;x,y,z)}\delta(r)\delta(z)$.

Next, a Fourier transform in the x-y plane is performed. I followed the following convention:

\begin{eqnarray}
f(k,z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}f(\vec{r}) d\vec{r},\\
f(\vec{r}) = \int e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}f(k,z) d\vec{k}.\\
\end{eqnarray}

Plug these to the Poisson's equation to get

$$(k^2-\partial_z^2)\phi(k,z) = \frac{4\pi}{\kappa}\rho(k)\delta(z).$$

Now, away from the singularity point $z=0$, the RHS is $0$, and we are essentially dealing with a Laplace's equation instead. Use separation of variables to write $\phi(k,z)=\phi_k(k)\phi_z(z)$ The general solution can then be written down for $z>0$ and $z<0$ as
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_{z_>}&=&Ae^{kr} + Be^{-kr}\\
\phi_{z_<}&=&Ce^{kr} + De^{-kr}.
\end{eqnarray}

The single(double)-gate geometry ensures that $\phi(z=d)=0, \phi(z=-\infty) = 0$($\phi(z=\pm d)=0$). To solve for the four variables $A,B,C,D$, we need two more equations:
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_{z_>}(z=0)&=&\phi_{z_<}(z=0),\\
\frac{d\phi_{z_>}}{dz}(z=0)-\frac{d\phi_{z_<}}{dz}(z=0)&=& -\frac{4\pi}{\kappa\phi_k}\rho(k).\\
\end{eqnarray}
The first equation comes from the fact that the Coulomb potential is always continuous, and the second equation comes from that the derivative of Coulomb potential has a discontinuity at $z=0$ is affected by the charge at $z=0$.

Solving these(as an example, I'm writing down the solution for the double-gate geometry), one gets

\begin{eqnarray}
A &=& D,\\
B &=& C,\\
B &=& -A e^{2kd},\\
A &=& -\frac{\pi}{\kappa \phi_k}\frac{\rho(k)e^{-kd}}{k \cosh(kd)}.
\end{eqnarray}
Together, one gets

$$\phi(k,z)=\frac{2\pi}{\kappa k}\frac{\rho(k)\sinh(k(d-|z|))}{\cosh(kd)}.$$

At $z=0$,

$$\phi(k,0)=\frac{2\pi}{\kappa k}\rho(k)\tanh(kd).$$

As $\rho(r)$ is just a delta function, its Fourier transform $\rho(k)$ is just $q$, the charge. So
$$\phi(k,0)=\frac{2\pi q}{\kappa k}\tanh(kd).$$

A more detailed derivation is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z2teIeIxb09c3RWFm2SgamyBy7I2koad/view?usp=share_link).